# How to wrap a span's text with display inline to fit a specified width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a span to wrap its text to fit a specified width, while displaying inline with its peer element.  It seems that whatever I try the text if too long runs beyond where I want it to stop and over and into the other element.

HTML:

```
<div class="LeftAdjustedText">
    <div class="FreeQuest">
        <span class="QuestText">We welcome any comments about your check-in experience</span><br>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="5" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
        <div><span class="QuestText CommentMaxLen">2000</span> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.LeftAdjustedText .FreeQuest{
    display: inline;
}

.LeftAdjustedText .FreeQuest span{
    width: 466px;
}
```

Comment: `width` has no effect on inline elements like spans. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in HTML and CSS, please take a look [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Achunath/2f4nLuek/)`

```
 <div class="FreeQuest">
        <span class="QuestText">We welcome any comments about your check-in experience</span><br>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="5" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
        <div><span class="CommentMaxLen">20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</span> </div>
    </div>
</div> 

.LeftAdjustedText .FreeQuest{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.QuestText {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
.LeftAdjustedText .FreeQuest span.CommentMaxLen{
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 70px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    float:left;
}
```

`